# Why browser does not refresh page?

Tags: asp.net

This is how I want it to work:

1. User clicks on button
2. Browser performs postback to server
3. Server executes function named onExportButtonClick
4. During onExportButtonClick execution user sees temporary page with rotating hourglass.
5. When onExportButtonClick is done user automatically goes to default page.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onExportButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Compare(DateCalendar.SelectedDate, DateTime.Today) > 0)
        DateCalendar.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;

    Response.Write("<html>");
    Response.Write("<head><title>IMAGEN - Export to Excel</title></head>");
    Response.Write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=FilesGenerated.aspx?PostBackUrl=Default.aspx'>");
    Response.Write("<body background='images/Background.jpg'>");
    Response.Write("<h1>Exporting database</h1><br />");
    Response.Write("<h2>Please Wait...</h2><br />");

    for (int index = 0; index < 50; index++)
        Response.Write("&nbsp;");

    Response.Write("<img src='images/hourglass_rotates.gif' />");
    Response.Flush();

    Export();

    Response.Write("</body></html>");
    Response.Flush();
}
```

It works with some browsers. Could you please help me understand why it does not work with other browsers.

Problem is - I (user) do not see hourglass. When I click button I see that browser is doing something (for a long time) and then goes directly to default page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution for IE8:

Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security

**Enable SmartScreen Filter** option must be enabled